# How get the stream from kafka topic to elasticsearch with confluent?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm read data from machine and stream it as JSON to a kafka topic. I would like to read this topic and store the streamdata into elasticsearch with confluent.

My steps:
1. Create KSQL Streams to convert from JSON to AVRO

json stream:

```
 CREATE STREAM source_json_pressure 
 (
  timestamp BIGINT, 
  opcuaObject VARCHAR, 
  value DOUBLE
  ) 
 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='7d12h100mbpressure',
   VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

avro stream:

```
 CREATE STREAM target_avro_pressure 
  WITH (
     KAFKA_TOPIC='7d12h100mbpressure_avro', 
     VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
  ) AS 
  SELECT * FROM source_json_pressure;
```

after this i get this avro stream:

```
 ksql> print "7d12h100mbpressure_avro";

 Format:AVRO
 23.04.19 19:29:58 MESZ,   jK?C, {"TIMESTAMP": 1556040449728, "OPCUAOBJECT": "DatLuDrUeb.EinDru", "VALUE": 7.42}
```

My elasticsearch.properties:

```
15 name=elasticsearch-sink
16 connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
17 tasks.max=1
18 topics=7d12h100mbpressure_avro
19 key.ignore=true
20 connection.url=http://localhost:9200
21 type.name=kafka-connect
```

After this i expect the stream in ES but i get the indices without the streamdata.

Where i make mistake?

ERRORS from confluent log connect:

```
 [2019-04-24 11:01:29,316] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-elasticsearch-sink] Setting newly assigned partitions: 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-3, 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-2, 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-1, 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:290)
 [2019-04-24 11:01:29,327] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-elasticsearch-sink] Resetting offset for partition 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-3 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:584)
 [2019-04-24 11:01:29,327] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-elasticsearch-sink] Resetting offset for partition 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-2 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:584)
 [2019-04-24 11:01:29,327] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-elasticsearch-sink] Resetting offset for partition 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-1 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:584)
 [2019-04-24 11:01:29,328] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-elasticsearch-sink] Resetting offset for partition 7d12h100mbpressure_avro-0 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:584)
 [2019-04-24 11:01:29,667] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic 7d12h100mbpressure_avro to Avro:
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more 
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 92747
 Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:226)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:252)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:482)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:475)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:151)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:230)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:209)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:116)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:215)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:145)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [2019-04-24 11:01:29,668] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
```

My connect-avro-distributed.properties:

```
 # Bootstrap Kafka servers. If multiple servers are specified, they should be comma-separated.
   bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

  key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
  value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

  config.storage.topic=connect-configs
  offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
  status.storage.topic=connect-statuses

  config.storage.replication.factor=1
  offset.storage.replication.factor=1
  status.storage.replication.factor=1

 internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
 internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Comment: It's not clear what command you ran to start Kafka Connect

Comment: i start confluent: "./confluent start" with zookeeper, kafka, ksql-server and more

Comment: Okay, then you ran `confluent load elasticsearch.properties`, then looked at Elasticsearch/Kibana and you see what?

Comment: if i load it, i create the indices "7d12h100mbpressure_avro" but without values

Comment: Is data actively being input to that topic? Connect starts and the latest offset by default.

Comment: If you do `confluent log connect`, do you see any errors?

Comment: Also can you please list connectors that are running on your connect cluster.

Comment: If you see your connector (elasticsearch-sink) in that list, Please check the status of that connector, you can check this from browser also by running http(s)://connect-hostname:8083/connectors

Comment: @ofitz can you share your Kafka Connect worker config? It's quite likely that your converters are not set correctly. Best is if you can edit your question to include any errors from your Kafka Connect worker log (`confluent log connect`), like @cricket_007 said.

Comment: @all yes , the input ist active and default. 

-logs are include in my question

-connectors list: zookeeper,  kafka,  schema-registry,  kafka-rest, connect and   ksql-server. If im browsing the connectors, the output is:  ["elasticsearch-sink"]   

-more infos i include to the question

Comment: This is the important exception, but how can i solve it:

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic 7d12h100mbpressure_avro to Avro:`

Comment: `Error retrieving Avro schema for id 92747` ... `RestClientException: Schema not found` ... I think you need to remove `key.converter` as the AvroConverter because KSQL doesn't create Avro keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `key.ignore=true` from the Elasticsink, however, that doesn't stop Connect from try to deserialize the record.

When you just do `confluent start`, it'll always uses `AvroConverter` for both key and value converters.

It's worth mentioning that, `VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'` in KSQL only makes the *value* as Avro, I believe, not the key.

One of those reasons might explain why you see one of

- subject not found
- schema not found
- Error retrieving Avro schema for id

To workaround this, in your `elasticsearch.properties` you can override `key.converter` to be something else like `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`

---

Also, rather than debugging with Connect+KSQL, I suggest using `kafka-avro-console-consumer` and including the `--property print.key=true` option to see if you get a similar error.

Comment: with `./kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic 7d12h100mbpressure_avro1 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`
is my output: `{"TIMESTAMP":{"long":1556171473227},"OPCUAOBJECT":{"string":"DatLuDrUeb.EinDru"},"VALUE":{"double":8.06}}`

if i set `--property print.key=true` i get the same error

Comment: which config file use confluent if i start it `./confluent start`?

i have  config in `confluent-5.2.1/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties` and `confluent-5.2.1/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties`

Comment: It uses `connect-avro-distributed.properties`. But like I said, you can override the converters in the Elasticsearch sink properties

Comment: thank you so much. after i override the `key.converter`it works!

how can i write more then one topic in elastic? can i config `elasticsearch.properties` for more than one topic like this: `topics=topic1, topic2`

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: FYI: KSQL support for keys in Avro format (and, in general, "structured keys") is upcoming.

Comment: How can i reset all setting of  ksql-server? I have created tables and streams and i would to delete all of them to start create new streams and tables